# Passing variables from php to python and python to php

Tags: php, python, exec

I am breaking my head to make this work but I am in a dead end. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
I play with php and python; trying to execute a python script through php exec(), return an output and pass it to another python script. 
This is my workflow:
1) Through jquery and an ajax request I pass some data to a php file (exec1.php) which looks like this:

```
$number = $_POST['numberOfClusters'];
$shape = $_POST['shapeFilePath'];
// EXECUTE THE PYTHON SCRIPT
$command = "python ./python/Module1.py $number $shape";
exec($command,$out,$ret);
print_r($out);
print_r($r); //return nicely 1.
```

2) The python file which I run Module1.py looks like this:

```
# this is a list of list of tuples
cls000 = [[(365325.342877, 4385460.998374), (365193.884409, 4385307.899807), (365433.717878, 4385148.9983749995)]]

# RETURN DATA TO PHP
print cls000
```

3) Then I have a nested AJAX request inside the success function of my previous AJAX request in which I pass the response (in this case the cls000 list) into a php script called (exec2.php) like this:

```
# PASS VARIABLES FROM FORM
$number = $_POST['numberOfClusters'];
$shape = $_POST['shapeFilePath'];
$clusterCoords = $_POST['response']; # response from previous Ajax request

// EXECUTE THE PYTHON SCRIPT 
$command = "python ./python/Module2.py $number $shape $clusterCoords";
exec($command,$out,$ret);

print_r($out); ## THIS GIVES ME AN EMPTY ARRAY!!
print_r($ret); ## THIS GIVES ME A RETURN STATUS: 2
```

4) My Module2.py script looks like this:

```
number = int(sys.argv[1])
shape =  sys.argv[2]
cls000 = json.loads(sys.argv[3])

# RETURN DATA TO PHP
print cls000
```

What am I doing wrong? If I remove this line 'cls000 = json.loads(sys.argv[9])' and return for example 'shape' everything works fine. But when I try to return cls000 I get a status code 2.
What am I missing here?